C# ajax post request 404 not found
I have an ajax query running from a page located in a folder Project/Pages/IT/NewEmailSetup
I want it to call a post request to a controller thats located in Project/Controllers/TestEmailSenderController
I have tried all manner of things but no matter what I do It just returns a 404 error.
My most recent test looks like the below:
Ajax Query:
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: '/Controllers/TestEmailSender/Send',
contentType: 'application/json',
data: { "EmailInfo": inner }
});

Then within my controller is the following:
[Route("Controllers/[controller]")]
public class TestEmailSenderController : Controller
{
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     return View();
 }
 [HttpPost]
 [Route("Send")]
 public ActionResult Send(string EmailInfo)
 {
 //Action code
 }
}

Any help would be much appreciated I am very new to ajax / websites in general.

EDIT
I have got this to work by adding the following to my StartupCS
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
 name: "default",
 pattern: "Controllers/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

My controller has been updated to
[Route("Controllers/[controller]/[Action]")]
public class TestEmailSenderController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Send([FromBody]EmailInfo EmailInfo)
    {
    //Action
    }
}

My ajax is now:
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: '/Controllers/TestEmailSender/Send',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   data: { inner }
});

My issue now is that whatever i do it always passes a null value to my controller.

Check the request from the Browser tools > Network tab, to see if it sends the request to "http://localhost:/Controllers/TestEmailSender/Send" correctly with "http://localhost:" is your current hosting application URI.

Use @Url.Action("Method","Controller")
it will make your path:
url: @Url.Action("Send","TestEmailSenderController ")

By the way , you can remove Route("save") and in the top route change
[Route("Controllers/[controller]")] to [Route("Controllers/[controller]/[Action]")]

I always have the data section of my ajax query set up like this:
data: { EmailInfo: inner }
The first part is the parameter name of the C# function and the second is the value you want to pass to it which I'm assuming you got from earlier in the javascript file (and console logged to make sure that isn't a null value to begin with)
